# react-native upload image react-native-fetch-blob

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to upload a file from mobile (iOS and Android) to Amazon S3.

I've tried various things using react-native-fetch-blob.

The latest idea is to use react-native-fetch-blob readfile

*RNFetchBlob.fs.readFile(image.path, 'base64').then(data => //upload here );*

but unfortunately this uploads a base64 version of the file, which does not display on the web.

How can I upload a simple image?

Comment: lots of solutions https://github.com/g6ling/React-Native-Tips/blob/master/How_to_upload_photo%2Cfile_in%20react-native/README.md

Comment: Thank you. That's where I got readFile, unfortunately I can't find any that allow me to upload as a JPEG file (for instance) rather than a JPEG encoded as Base64. I need to be able to display the resulting file in a webbrowser.

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me:

```
RNFetchBlob.fetch(
  'POST',
  `${BASE_URL}vehicle/vehicleRegistration`,
  {
    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + authToken,
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data,octet-stream',
  },
  [
    {
      name: 'photo',
      filename: 'vid.mp4',
      data: RNFetchBlob.wrap(vehicleImage.uri),
    },
    {
      name: 'email',
      data: user.email,
    },
    {
      name: 'userId',
      data: user.id,
    },
    {
      name: 'vehicleType',
      data: values.vehicleType,
    },
    {
      name: 'make',
      data: values.make,
    },
    {
      name: 'buildYear',
      data: values.buildYear,
    },
    {
      name: 'model',
      data: values.model,
    },
    {
      name: 'nickName',
      data: values.nickName,
    },
    {
      name: 'engineSize',
      data: values.engineSize,
    },
  ],
)
  .uploadProgress((written, total) => {
    console.log('uploaded', written / total);
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(RetrivedData => {
    console.log('---retrieved data------', RetrivedData);
    Toast.show({
      text1: 'Success',
      text2: 'Vehicle Added to Garage!',
      type: 'success',
    });
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('----Error in adding a comment----', err);
    Toast.show({
      text1: 'Request Failed',
      text2: err?.response?.data?.message,
      type: 'error',
    });
  });
```